# Aligning decimal numbers in Flex datagrid column

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

The dataProvider for my Flex DataGridColumn contains numbers with various number of decimals. For example: 0.45, 122.3, 0.003

How can I show the numbers aligned with respect to their decimal point (i.e. the decimal points are aligned vertically in the column) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue, you'll need to write your custom itemRenderer. In this renderer I'd suggest you to split your numbers with point into parts (example "0.45" -> "0" and ".45"), create `Label` for each part and try to align right parts (with point) identically. And then join the left part.

Comment: Thanks. It can work, although a bit clunky. Since I asked the question, it occured to me, isn't there a solution with single label, using fixed width font ?